# Excel Functions not Differentiating Some Arabic Letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, arabic

I have a table in excel with some Arabic letters/words with their id numbers; that is a table of two columns as such:

```
ID          Letter
ء           1
2           آ
3           أ
4           إ
5           لا
6           لإ
7           ئ
8           ا
9           ـا
10          لأ
11          ـلا
12          ب
13          بـ
14          ـب
15           ـبـ
```

What I want is to be able to retrieve the id of the letter after I enter the letter in another sheet.
I have used both the match and vlookup excel functions and they seem to work fine.  However, the problem is that it does not identify the letters correctly.

```
So, for example, if I enter ء I get 1 - which is correct.
If I enter آ I get 2 - which is correct.
If I enter أ I get 2 - which is incorrect, it should return 3
If I enter إ I get 2 - which is incorrect, it should return 4
If I enter ب I get 12 - which is correct.
If I enter بـ I get 13 - which is correct.
If I enter ـب I get 13 - which is incorrect, it should return 14
If I enter ـبـ I get 12 - which is incorrect, it should return 15
```

The formula I am using for the vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2; Full!$A$3:$E$145; 2; FALSE)
```

where: `A2` has the letter I enter
`Full!$A$3:$E$145` is the table with my data
`2` is the number of the column I want to get the data from
`False` because I want an exact match

What could be the problem?

Comment: What are your formulas?

Comment: I have edited the question to include that information

Comment: I do not speak nor write Arabic, but I do know that the same character uses a different glyph depending on its position in a word or it it's on its own. Could this be causing the problem? (i.e. a certain glyph is shown, but Excel looks for the "standalone" glyph?)

Comment: I think that might be causing the problem, but how can I work around it?  For example, the second arabic letter as a standalone is ب . But in arabic, the letters can be connected, so the same letter at the beginning of a word transforms to بـ where an extra letter or glyph as you say (that looks like an underscore is added).  Whereas at the end of a word, you will find this letter to look like:ـب where they glyph precedes it.  When the letter is in the middle of a word it will have a glyph both before and after it as such: ـبـ

Comment: Two quick question: 1) are you willing to have a helper column? 2) Does the problem also appear with words, or only single characters?

Comment: 1. Any helper column is welcome.  I was actually looking into doing that now by converting to unicode and working with that - still haven't fully thought it out though.  2. I am currently working with cells made up of 1, 2 or max 3 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure someone smarter will come up with something more elegant, but here is a kludge that works for any sample 3 or fewer characters long:

1. Add a sixth column to your table populated with the following formula:

   ```
   =CHOOSE(LEN(B2),UNICODE(B2),UNICODE(B2) & UNICODE(MID(B2,2,1)),UNICODE(B2) & UNICODE(MID(B2,2,1)) & UNICODE(RIGHT(B2,1)))
   ```

(Where I assumed column `B` is where the Arabic text is in your table)

2. Then use the following formula to get the row in the table:

   ```
   =MATCH(CHOOSE(LEN(A2),UNICODE(A2),UNICODE(A2) & UNICODE(MID(A2,2,1)),UNICODE(A2) & UNICODE(MID(A2,2,1)) & UNICODE(RIGHT(A2,1))),Full!F$2:F$16,0)
   ```

(where `A2` is where you enter the looked for text and `Full!F$2:F$16` is the column with the formula inserted in step 1)

Once you have a match, you can use `INDEX` to retrieve whatever data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNICODE() formula to provide an id that can be compared properly.

I've created a new column A on the Sheet "Full" (id is now moved to column B and Arabic letters to column C), formula on column A is as follows for cell A25 in the sheet Full:

```
=UNICODE(C25)
```

Then the formula to retrieve the id would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(UNICODE(A2); Full!$A$3:$B$145; 2; FALSE)
```

where A2 is where you put the arabic letter you want to know the id.